# Read-only mode for logical disk with FAT32

Tags: windows, readonly, fat32, removable-storage, dacl

How can I set in Windows 'read-only' mode for specific logical disk (like F:), which formatted by FAT32? I know about access permissions politic for removable storage in gpedit.msc, but they works for all logical disk together. I want setting this mode via disk names (F: H: etc). How can I do it? I had tried to write simple C# code, which change access permissions for disk, but it does't work for FAT disks:

```cs
System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity d = System.IO.Directory.GetAccessControl("F:\\");
SecurityIdentifier everyone = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
FileSystemAccessRule accRule = new FileSystemAccessRule(everyone, FileSystemRights.Write, AccessControlType.Deny);
d.AddAccessRule(accRule);
System.IO.Directory.SetAccessControl("F:\\", d);
```

Comment: You need to set the volume's read-only flag.  I know you can do that in diskpart (though I've never tried with a FAT32 volume) but I'm not sure how to do it programatically.  The posted code sets permissions on the root directory, which won't work since FAT32 doesn't have file permissions.